# Cocoa/objectiveC UI design issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to build an app on MacOSX - ObjectiveC. I don't not find a good ressource to understand how I can create the view I need and the steps to made it.

I'm looking mostly to create 3 sections.

Section 1: Few buttons and one image
Section 2: TreeView to have a File browser/finder
Section 3: Progress bar to show the disk usage.

I'm creating an app to read android device and manage file transfer. Such as Android File Transfer.

Comment: You might consider reading about Android File Transfer over at [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56090/why-is-android-file-transfer-necessary). It might be a little more complicated.

Comment: I already develop the app but in Qt/C++. Just want to port it to ObjectiveC

Comment: did any of the below links help ?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you need to look over the tutorial that Apple provides on creating your [first Mac app](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/GettingStarted.html).

Second you can use `NSOutlineView` to create your treeview, [here's](http://devcry.heiho.net/2012/02/treeview-in-cocoa-nsoutlineview.html) a tutorial on this.

Then you need `NSProgressIndicator` for your progress bar, [here's](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/05/03/cocoa-tutorial-file-copy-with-progress-indicator/) a tutorial.

I also suggest you look over at [ray's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/category/os-x) tutorials to get started with XCode and all the interface builder tools.